# VS2017 linker issue: LNK1181 cannot open input file "glew32s.lib\\glew32s.lib\\glew32s.lib\\"

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017, glew

I am using **VS2017** for Cuda Application using glew library and when I try to build my code this error appears up.

So to add glew I have

1-Specified **GL/glew.h** in code.

2-I have linked in additional directories.

3-I have added glew32s.lib also in my additional directories.

So can someone please help me out in knowing whats the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: If that is the exact text of error of course it can't open that file. I mean 'glew32s.lib\\glew32s.lib\\glew32s.lib\\' is not a file. If you made a mistake typing copy the exact text of the error message from the Output Tab (not the errors list).

Comment: Again if this is the error message then you made a typing mistake at step 3. If this is not the error then the library you used at step 3 was wrong. It is either corrupt or you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Actually, this is the exact error and you are right this is not the file in my additional directory the file name is glew32s.lib. Even if I change to "NO" dependencies for additional library even than I get this error.

Comment: Are you using `CMake`?

Comment: No, I am putting the code directly in VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to use some package manager to don't bother with compiler/linker flags.
I suggest you use vcpk:

- [here](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial) some tutorials with some examples
- [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/09/19/vcpkg-a-tool-to-acquire-and-build-c-open-source-libraries-on-windows/) a list of libraries (glew is present)